# Angular JS Service not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create a universally accessible array in my application using services. I also implement ui-router in my appliaction.
I create the service in my app.js:

```
myFamilyApp.service('global', function() {
    var eventArray = [];

    return {
        addEvent: function() {
            eventArray.push(newObj);
        }
    }
});
```

then I call it from my controller:

```
myFamilyApp.controller('newEventController', [ '$scope', '$state',
    function($scope, $state, global) {
    eventConfig = {//variables to create event};
    e = new Event(eventConfig);
    global.addEvent(e);
```

});

but for some reason I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined

I know the issue is that the controller not recognizing the global variable, but I don't know why. I've looked at several other posts and generally messed around with it but I can't figure out why my controllers access the service. Any ideas?

Comment: Typo is in front of your eyes.. :) You forgot to specify it in the injection list. `myFamilyApp.controller('newEventController', [ '$scope', '$state', 'global',
    function($scope, $state, global) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized my problem, and I apologize for posting this question I am still very new to angular. My issue was very simple, I wasn't passing in the 'global' when i created my controller
`myFamilyApp.controller('newEventController', [ '$scope', '$state', 'global', function (params)`